# Формирования запроса Select DESC

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток! У меня проблема с выводом топа, вот собственно запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `turnir` ORDER BY `win` DESC LIMIT 1
```

он почему то берёт не наибольшее количество `win` а рандомно. На пример есть `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` он не выведет `9`, даже трудно сказать то что рандомно, потому что это число не меняется каждый раз а так и остаётся. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: предлагаю посмотреть результат запроса без LIMIT, думаю сразу понятно станет в чем проблема.

Comment: Для поля **win** задан тип **integer**?

Comment: @bazaev05 я имел в виду посмотреть на всю картину запроса, не только 1-ый элемент )

Comment: > Поле varchar(255

Вот вам, батенька, и ответ на вопрос. ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменил тип с VARCHAR на INT. 
Deonis++